# Replace multiple strings in text with reg ex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some text sprinkled with `[cid:ce743cbf-8c44-4c84-aa72-6d2c9eb4b81a]` labels (inline attachments)

I need to go through the text and replace it with the links to the file.
So I need to match the actual label with the brackets and remember the UUID within to be given to the replace function as a parameter.

So given the string

`var str = "some text 1 [cid:12345] more text follows 2 [cid:6789] last text"`

I am trying to replace it with this test but it does not even match correctly.

`str.replace(/\[cid:(.+)\]/gm, function(m,p){return p})`

I don't know much about reg ex, please help. I reckon it is something to do with greediness as it consumes everything between the first match and the last.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` is a [**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) operator meaning it will match as much as it can and still allow the remainder of the regular expression to match. Use `+?` for a non-greedy match meaning "one or more — preferably as few as possible".

```
/\[cid:(.+?)]/g
```

**Note:** You can remove the `m` (multi-line) modifier, it's meaningless to use here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct that is has to do with greediness. The `.+` part will match everything to the end of the string, and then it will start to backtrack to match the bracket, finding the last bracket in the string.

Adding `?` after the `.+` will make it non-greedy:

```js
var str = "some text 1 [cid:12345] more text follows 2 [cid:6789] last text"

str = str.replace(/\[cid:(.+?)\]/gm, function(m,p){return p});

// show in Stackoverflow snippet
document.write(str);
```

An alternative is to match everything except the closing bracket:

```
str = str.replace(/\[cid:([^\]]+)\]/gm, function(m,p){return p});
```